# Can we put [Cited in Page X] in Bibliography?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

Is there a method to put:

[image]

I am not sure is it called hyperlink or any MWE to start with.

Comment: These things are usually called backreferences/backrefs in the TeX world. How you can obtain them depends on the bibliography/citation package you use. (There is the `backref` package for most BibTeX-based solutions, `biblatex` has a `backref` option.)

Comment: @moewe. Thanks. I able to search and found your answer . I have another follow question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524911/how-to-change-the-format-of-backref-i-want-cited-on-page-x